# Have people explored the problem of regular expressions being matchable?

Tags: regular-expressions

I ran into a problem of determining if two regular expressions would have any possible matches in common. For example:

```
Fo*bar and Fo+bar
```

More specifically:

1. if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are two regular languages
2. can one determine if $R_1 \cap R_2 = \varnothing$ ?
3. And if one can what algorithms / methods can perform such a determination?
4. And are these algorithms / method NP hard?

Comment: This is not a research-level question. Hint: regular languages are closed under intersection.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek -- thank you for the hint -- I guess my questions was that even if the intersection is closed -- is it determinable if the intersection is the null set of not. Not sure if your hint answers this question -- I reformulated the question -- thanks

Comment: Determining whether or not two regular languages have a non-empty intersection is a research-level problem that I've dedicated several years studying.  There are many different variants to this problem depending on how the regular languages are represented.

Comment: In your case, your considering the problem where you're given two regular expressions and you want to determine if their corresponding regular languages have a non-empty intersection.

Comment: If $n$ denotes the length (in terms of number of characters) of the regular expressions, then we should be able to solve the problem in roughly $n^2$ time.  First, you convert the regular expressions to NFA's.  Then, you apply the product construction to the NFA's.  Then, you check if there exists a path from the product start state to the product final state in the product NFA's state diagram.  If there exists such a path, then the intersection is non-empty.  If there does not, then the intersection is empty.

Comment: If we could solve this problem in $n^{2-\varepsilon}$ time for some positive $\varepsilon$, then we would get faster algorithms for SAT and other problems.

Comment: There are some simple classes of regular expressions where we can solve it in $n^{2-\varepsilon}$ time.  Please feel free to message me anytime about this or related problems.  :)

Comment: In computer software, the term regular expression often refers to something more complex than the basic theoretical notion.  For example, take a look at the Java Pattern class with its documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: This relates to some of the theoretical notions of extended regular expressions.  For some classes of extended regular expressions, the intersection problem is much harder.

Comment: In other words, solving the intersection problem in practice for software developers can be a bit more complex.  I met a few people who put some thought into this.  :)